# How can I stick printed pictures on my leased condo's walls?

Tags: walls

I cut out the pretty pictures from travel guides that are mailed to me. How can I stick them to my condo's walls without harming the walls at all?

I lease my condo and my landlord's very strict. I definitely can't glue or tape the pictures to my wall. Some pictures of my walls -

[image]

Comment: ask your landlord about using sewing pins ..... they leave a very tiny hole

Answer (score 2):

**You need sticky tack**

I remember this from when I was a kid and it worked better back then. But it still works great and it's cheap.
[image]www.lowes.com

You just use a little ball in each corner and press it into the wall. Simply remove by pulling when you move.

Comment: Sometimes at removal, especially when the tac has been in place for a long time it can want to leave some residue on the wall. You can either rub it off or use a ball of new tac to roll over the spot and soften up the residue and it will come off with the ball.

Comment: You can also get white tack that is less likely to stain, though I've never had the blue stuff stain either.

Comment: i've had blue and white both leave behind what looks like grease stains. fwiw, the last pack i bought, manco, seems to work well w/o residue. It actually works a little too well: i've pulled paint and chunks of plaster out of the wall hanging some heavier items (framed pictures, smartphones) with it.

Answer (score 0):

What about washi tape? I know you said you can't tape stuff to the walls, but washi tape tends to not be very sticky and makes for pretty decoration, too :) (blue/white tack is definitely also your friend, though, as per the other answer!)

Comment: Can confirm - bought washi tape for my kids crafts and was very disappointed in how not sticky it was.  It would work good to _barely_ stick something to the wall.